# Do I lose rep when an answer that was accepted first, is unaccepted

Tags: support, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Do I lose rep when an answer that was accepted first, is unaccepted?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the reputation gained form that answer being accepted is removed when it gets un-accepted

Comment: You don't immediately lose it, but I was under the impression that a recalc would caused you to lose it.

Comment: @R.Bemrose, I believe you immediately lose it. I don't think you have to wait for a recalc.